# Call a function within a jQuery plugin using variable name

Tags: jquery

I have the below code.

```
(function($) {

    var myFunction = function(element) {

        var myCallerFunction = function() {
            var functionName = 'myInternalCallFunction';
            myFunction[functionName]();
            console.log(2);

        }

        var myInternalCallFunction = function() {

            console.log(1);
        }

        myCallerFunction();

    }

    $.fn.myfunction = function(options) {
        var func = new myFunction();
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Inside myCallerFunction I created a variable which holds the function name I want to call. I then try to call it, however it returns that it can't find the function. It finds the namespace myFunction okay as if I change:

```
myFunction[functionName]();
```

to

```
myFunctionTest[functionName]();
```

It returns it can't find "myFunctionTest" instead of not being able to find "myInterncalCallFunction".

Any ideas why it can't find the function?

Comment: You are defining `myInternalCallFunction` too late. It simply doesn't exist yet (and isn't a property of myFunction)

Comment: You can't retrieve local variables dynamically, they have to be properties of some objct. And `myInternalCallFunction` is not a property of `myFunction` btw.

Comment: Take a look now, I amended it - incorrect code was posted before! I'm just calling $().myfunction() and in Firebug it comes up with "TypeError: myFunction[functionName] is not a function"

Comment: @Ashley yes, because `myFunction[functionName]` is actually `undefined`.. did you read my comment?

Comment: Here: `myFunction[functionName]` `functionName` is being called as a property of an Object instead of a parameter of the function for what I can see. Have you tried wrapping everything up in an object and calling the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `myFunction['myInternalCallFunction']()` you are actually calling `myFunction.myInternalCallFunction()`. Of course, it is undefined since `myInternalCallFunction` is not a property of `myFunction`, it is its private variable. One way of solving this while not turning private variables to properties:

```
(function($) {

    var myFunction = function(element) {
        var cache = {};
        var myCallerFunction = function() {
            var functionName = 'myInternalCallFunction';
            cache[functionName]();
            console.log(2);

        }

        cache.myInternalCallFunction = function() {

            console.log(1);
        }

        myCallerFunction();

    }

    $.fn.myfunction = function(options) {
        var func = new myFunction();
    }

})(jQuery);
```